# Locate internal links containing specific parameter

Tags: web-crawler

I'm trying figure out how to crawl a website and locate links that contain a specific tracking parameter.  Reason: some of our content authors have appended a ?campaign=test to a number of internal links on our website (which contains several thousand pages).  These parameters pollute analytics results and need to be removed.  But of course I first have to find them all...

I figure that a custom crawler could do the trick,but I'm not a programmer.  Most link checkers only report on broken links rather than a specific link parameter.  Maybe I'm just missing something very obvious?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your scenario with **Norconex HTTP Collector** (free/open-source) and it gives what you want without having to write code.

First, download Norconex HTTP Collector from this location: http://www.norconex.com/product/collector-http/. You will be suggested to also download a "Committer" but you do not need to in this case.

Second, extract the downloaded zip in a directory of your choice.

In that directory, create yourself a configuration file (let's call it "links-detector.xml") and copy the following in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<httpcollector id="Link Locator Collector">

  #set($workdir = "/path/of/your/choice")

  <!-- Decide where to store generated files. -->
  <progressDir>${workdir}/progress</progressDir>
  <logsDir>${workdir}/logs</logsDir>

  <crawlers>
    <crawler id="Link Locator Crawler">

      <startURLs>
        <!-- Replace with the start URL to your site -->
        <url>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page</url>
      </startURLs>

      <workDir>${workdir}</workDir>

      <!-- Increase to match your site. -->
      <maxDepth>1</maxDepth>

      <!-- Hit interval, in milliseconds. -->
      <delay default="1000" />

      <numThreads>2</numThreads>

      <robotsTxt ignore="true" />

      <!-- At a minimum make sure you stay on your domain. -->
      <httpURLFilters>
        <filter class="com.norconex.collector.http.filter.impl.RegexURLFilter"
                onMatch="include" >
          http://en\.wikipedia\.org/wiki/.*
        </filter>
      </httpURLFilters>

      <!-- This filter will only accept URLs with ":" in them after 
           URLs were extracted for further crawling. 
           Change to match your pattern -->
      <httpDocumentFilters>
        <filter class="com.norconex.collector.http.filter.impl.RegexURLFilter"
                onMatch="include" >
          http://.*:.*
        </filter>
      </httpDocumentFilters>

      <!-- We do not want to store the data anywhere. -->
      <committer class="com.norconex.committer.impl.NilCommitter" />
    </crawler>
  </crawlers>

</httpcollector>
```

That configuration was used to test the detection of wikipedia URLs that had the ":" character in them.  Modify the configuration values as indicated to match your own needs (i.e. change the start URLs, update the regular expressions, etc).

If you are not familiar with regular expressions, this should match your scenario:  `.*\?campaign=test.*`.

You will find all matching URLs under the logs/latest directory and they will be printed to the console as well.   You will have too much stuff printed out though.  To restrict the output to only the matching URLs you are after, modify the `classes/log4j.properties` files.  Change all the loglevels to WARN except this one (keeping it at INFO): `log4j.logger.com.norconex.collector.http.crawler.CrawlStatus.OK=INFO`.

Once you have done all that, you can give it a try by running this (replace .bat by .sh if on Unix/Linux):

```
collector-http.bat -a start -c links-detector.xml
```

Unless there are errors, the output should give you all the links matching your pattern on your site.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Site Visualizer Pro](http://site-visualizer.com) website crawler to do this.

1. Click '**Project -> New**', specify URL of your website, then click **OK** and **Start** button.
2. After the crawling is finished, go to **Database** tab of Site Visualizer's main window, then execute the following SQL query: (copy & paste the text and click **Execute** button)

`select * from links where to_url like '%campaign=test%'`

You'll be given all the links you need at the bottom of the window (replace my *'%f=3%'* example with yours *'%campaign=test%'*):

[image]

There are many columns describing every link (content type, response, anchor text, source code, etc.), but I think you'll only need **from_url** (to know what page exactly contains such 'campaign=test' link) and **to_url** (to know what page the link references to) columns.

Press **Ctrl+A** shortcut, then right-click on the result table and choose '**Copy Rows with Headers**' context-menu command. After that, you'll be able to paste the data to an MS Excel sheet, or similar application.

Site Visualizer Pro has 30-day fully-functional trial period, so you can do your task at no cost.